# ASP.NET C# help me about sum or minus in amount

Tags: c#, winforms

```html
<table style="width:80%">
  <tr align="Left">
    <th>Member_No</th>
    <th>Member_Name</th> 
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Entry_Type</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A-251</td>
    <td>Alpesh</td> 
    <td>2000</td>
    <td>Credit</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A-252</td>
    <td>Haresh</td> 
    <td>2000</td>
    <td>Debit</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A-253</td>
    <td>Suresh</td> 
    <td>2000</td>
    <td>Debit</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A-254</td>
    <td>Johny</td> 
    <td>5000</td>
    <td>Credit</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A-255</td>
    <td>Vishal</td> 
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>Debit</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am using `DataGridView` for display table data
I need a total Amount of above column `Amount` in `TextBox` or `Label` when I click on total button
but when `entry_Type` is `Credit` then its do sum

& when `entry_Type` is `Debit` then its do subtract

please help me for above
C# Winform

Comment: This is a plain HTML code. What doest it have to do with C#? ... and WinForm?

Comment: its table from my gridview i just make it for understand

Comment: WinForm with HTML part? ... sorry I just don't get it. I'm quite sure that this is *not* part of gridView in WinForm. Even if it would... by some magic... there are not enough details to answer your question.

Comment: no i just put here for understand my gridview table<br> icant put images so i put this

Comment: run code snippet then see my table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var total = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Sum(x => x.Cells[3].Value.ToString() == "Credit"? int.Parse(x.Cells[2].Value.ToString()) :  -(int.Parse(x.Cells[2].Value.ToString())))
            .ToString();
textBox1.Text = total;
```

Comment: i have total amount.. then i need to do sum when credit amount & subtract when debit amount

Comment: Don't expect SO to be place to spoon feed you! @user2946329 has already given a logic, now build on it, instead of blindly adding Cells[2].Value, you need to check something else and decide whether to add or subtract.If you can't figure that out you deserve to fail in your school assignment.

Comment: yah! now u understand my question.. sorry for i cant explain very well